# Running a Folder of R Scripts, each in a different R instance

Tags: java, python, r

I have a folder of scripts that I need to run, however I need to run them in parallel.

How can I run a folder of R scripts, each one in a different instance of R?
EG. 
10 R scripts run on 10 instances of R, simultaneously.

Previously I have just opened R manually 10 times and the run each script by copying and pasting it in, however I was wondering if there is a way I could automate this?

I don't necessarily need to do this within R - I am open to the use of other languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an R-only solution, and should work regardless of your OS:

```
Rfiles <- dir("your.folder", pattern="\\.[R|r]$", full.names=TRUE)
library(parallel)
clus <- makeCluster(length(Rfiles))
parLapply(clus, Rfiles, source)
```

Answer (score 3):

An extremely simple way to do what you are describing is with a `bash` script something like this:

```
for R_FILE in $(ls *.R)
do
    R CMD BATCH $R_FILE &
done
```

If you are using Windows you would need the Cygwin stuff installed, but on Linux or Mac you are good to go.

Comment: This suggestion also worked - however, I am more comfortable with using R so accepted their answer instead. But your answer was equally helpful! Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Rscript from a shell. How to run multiple simultaneous commands is shell-specific. For instance, this would work on the bash shell:

```
Rscript file1.R &
Rscript file2.R &
```