# How to create an R Script to run R Scripts located in a specific folder?

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript

I am using RStudio (OS: Windows 10) and I have around 10 R scripts located in a specific folder on my C drive.

I am looking for an R Script that can execute those R Scripts in the folder one after the other (not in parallel).

Also, I need the RScripts to run in RStudio and not in a Command Prompt Window.

**Additional info:**

R scripts location: C:\myfiles\R\Rscripts
List of RScripts in that folder (extract shown):

08dec22-15dec22.R

21jan22-27jan22.R

10feb23-17feb23.R

...

I checked the answers provided here but I cannot figure out how to customize them for my needs: [Running a Folder of R Scripts, each in a different R instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534779/running-a-folder-of-r-scripts-each-in-a-different-r-instance)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using `source()` for each script in the succession that you want will achieve this.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point to a solution somewhere please?

Comment: Hmm, this one seems close to it, although it wasn't accepted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514710/the-source-function-in-r

Comment: Not having looked at @Phil 's link, you might look at [Hauer - IRS migration data](https://github.com/mathewhauer/IRS-migration-data), but I'm only in terminal so can't comment on RStudio and differences.

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you asking how to put the path?  Did you read the help file for `source()`?

Comment: @Elin I am trying to figure out how to write the R script that will trigger the R scripts in that folder.

Comment: And we have told you to make a file with a source("filepath") for each file.  Did you read the help file? Did you try using source()?

Comment: @Elin Gone through it. Makes sense and it works! Thanks.